# Perfect Hash Functions

Tags: function, data-structures, hash

I was recently given a homework that asked whether given a list of keys it would be possible to make a hash function that doesnt have any collisions. Doing some research, I found out that given a preordered list of keys, perfect hash functions are possible.

However, I'm not quite sure what to say beyond that. Could anyone give me some advice on how perfect hash functions are made, or what exactly giving a predefined list does to a hash function creator that allows for a perfect function?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to have no collisions is to have a 1-to-1 relationship between the key and the hash value. The range of hash values must be at least as large as the number of keys, and the mapping function must transform each key to a unique value. Much more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash

Answer (score 0):

In CLRS book, section 11.5 "Perfect hashing", we find how given a fixed set of `n` input keys, we can build a hash-table with no collision. Outline:

- if we can afford table size `m = n*n`, then based on Theorem 11.9 (quoted below) in that section, we know that we can easily find a hash-function from a universal-class of hash-functions, which gives no collision.
- otherwise, "secondary hash tables" can be kept for any slot with more than 1 key. Such table itself can be built based on the idea of Theorem 11.9, because now the number of keys `nj`, in that slot, are small, and so will be `nj*nj`.

Theorem 11.9, quoted:
"If we store `n` keys in a hash table of size `m=n*n` using a hash function `h` randomly chosen from a universal class of hash functions, then the probability of there being any collisions is less than 1/2."